# MySQL: Unable to fulling forward engineering Sakila (sample) into server

Tags: sql, mysql

After download the Sakila (sample), I have try to forward engineering this Schema into the server but only part of the table was engineered. Later synchronize also fall. Please take a look the report below and tell me is what wrong. I dont have programming background.

If someone have successfully forward engineer Sakila fully, let me know.

Executing SQL script in server

> ERROR: Error 1253: COLLATION 'latin1_swedish_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'

Scripts:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sakila`.`customer` (
  `customer_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `store_id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `address_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE ,
  `create_date` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  `last_update` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`) ,
  INDEX `idx_fk_store_id` (`store_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `idx_fk_address_id` (`address_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `idx_last_name` (`last_name` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_address` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id` ) REFERENCES `sakila`.`address` (`address_id` ) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_store` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id` ) REFERENCES `sakila`.`store` (`store_id` ) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB 
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci

COMMENT = 'Table storing all customers. Holds foreign keys to the address table and the store table where this customer is registered.\n\nBasic information about the customer like first and last name are stored in the table itself. Same for the date the record was created and when the information was last updated.'
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed

Answer (score 0):

sakila-schema.sql works fine for me.

If you remove this line then your create table statement should work:

```
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci
```