# MySQL: Error 1628: Comment for table 'customer' is too long (max = 60)

Tags: sql, mysql

After fixing Error 1253 ([MySQL: Unable to fulling forward engineering Sakila (sample) into server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567808/mysql-unable-to-fulling-forward-engineering-sakila-sample-into-server)), I have Error 1628.

Executing SQL script in server

> ERROR: Error 1628: Comment for table 'customer' is too long (max = 60)

Scripts:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sakila`.`customer` (

  `customer_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

  `store_id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,

  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

  `email` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,

  `address_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,

  `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE ,

  `create_date` DATETIME NOT NULL ,

  `last_update` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`) ,

  INDEX `idx_fk_store_id` (`store_id` ASC) ,

  INDEX `idx_fk_address_id` (`address_id` ASC) ,

  INDEX `idx_last_name` (`last_name` ASC) ,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_address`

    FOREIGN KEY (`address_id` )

    REFERENCES `sakila`.`address` (`address_id` )

    ON DELETE RESTRICT

    ON UPDATE CASCADE,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_store`

    FOREIGN KEY (`store_id` )

    REFERENCES `sakila`.`store` (`store_id` )

    ON DELETE RESTRICT

    ON UPDATE CASCADE)

ENGINE = InnoDB

DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

**COMMENT** 'Table storing all customers. Holds foreign keys to the address table and the store table where this customer is registered.\n\nBasic information about the customer like first and last name are stored in the table itself. Same for the date the record was created and when the information was last updated.'

SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed

Comment: the error message seems quite straightforward...

Comment: You never actually asked a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the MySQL docs, a comment is limited to 255 characters: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html#id3411882. Your comment is 305 characters, and it would seem, from the error message, that your particular MySQL install has a 60 character limit.

Answer (score 7):

As an addition: More current versions (5.6.X) allow longer comments. Unfortunately this length differs from the type of comment:

For `tables`: *"A comment for the table, up to 2048 characters long."*

For `columns`: *"A comment for a column can be specified with the COMMENT option, up to 1024 characters long."*

For `INDEX`: *"In MySQL 5.6, index definitions can include an optional comment of up to 1024 characters."*

For `PARTITION`: *"Beginning with MySQL 5.6.6, the maximum length for a partition comment is 1024 characters. (Previously, this limit was not explicitly defined.)"*

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html

Comment: It seems to differ for the `COMMENT` string in stored procedures though ... I have 2 MySQL servers (essentially hosting identical databases) and when I put the stored procedure on one the creation failed when the comment was 77 characters but was fine with 63 ... the other server was happy with 77. Fractionally different SQL versions (since one's on Debian and their version of the stack).